# Store Firebase Real Time Database data in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to automatically have firebase database data be stored as different documents in Firestore? I've thought of trying to use Cloud Functions to achieve this, but I'm not familiar with javascript at all.

I'm an engineering student working on an automated garden project. I decided that it would be cool to have an app that updates with the real-time data (updated every 5min) as well as historical data that shows all of the previous update values. I've got an ESP8266 coded from Arduino IDE to update my Realtime Database with the sensor values, but I can't figure out the best way to store these values in order to view the historical data. If there is a better way of doing this I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to automatically have firebase database data be stored as different documents in Firestore? I've thought of trying to use Cloud Functions to achieve this, but I'm not familiar with javascript at all.

Yes, it's possible, and yes, you can use Cloud Functions for this.  You don't have to be familiar with JavaScript as Cloud Functions supports [several languages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing) in Google Cloud Platform.  The Firebase tools only support JavaScript, but you don't have to use that if you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll look more into Cloud Functions. Any advice you have would be appreciated!